# max file descriptors for elasticsearch process is too low

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch

Cannot resolve these problems:

```
[2017-10-16T13:54:23,381][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node-1] max 
file descriptors [65000] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to 
at least [65536]
[2017-10-16T13:54:23,382][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node-1] max 
number of threads [1024] for user [appadm01] is too low, increase to at 
least [2048]
[2017-10-16T13:54:23,382][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node-1] system 
call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or 
disable system call filters at your own risk
```

I executed sysctl -w fs.file-max=65536 but I get the same thing.

Answer (score 18):

For those who are using docker for running elastic search then you can set ulimit through your `docker run` command like below.

```
docker run --ulimit nofile=65536:65536 -p 9200:9200 --name elastic-search docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.2
```

Hope this will help docker users

Answer (score 13):

Try this: (got it from 2-3 different sources)

add in `$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml`

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
```

If its local dev setup, also use lesser memory options if possible:

add/modify in `$ES_HOME/config/jvm.options`

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Thanks, This is worked for me, initialy I have added only "network.host: 0.0.0.0". After adding all above mention, it working without any issue. Thanks lot.

Comment: in ES 8.8.2 the settin is now "transport.port: 9300". With this small difference , it still worked.

Answer (score 7):

Just create a systemd service like this, watch closely the ulimit nofile settings :
vi /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Spin ES Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=<user name>
Group=<group name>
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/<user>/elasticsearch-6.4.3/bin/elasticsearch
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
LimitAS=infinity
LimitRSS=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where the ExecStart needs to have "which bash" followed by your $ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch

Also, my settings for users are these :

```
ulimit -n 65536
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
fs.file-max = 2097152
vm.max_map_count = 262144
vm.swappiness = 1
```

followed by:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply Update /etc/security/limits.conf content to below

```
elasticsearch   soft    nofile          65536
elasticsearch   hard    nofile          65536
elasticsearch   memlock unlimited
```

and remove content of /etc/security/limits.d/nproc.conf

Do not forgot to relogin into the shell in order to get the limits applied.

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing the same issue while configuring the sonarqube and was able to resolve the issue by adding the **LimitNOFILE=65536** param in the /etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=SonarQube service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop

User=sonarqube
Group=sonarqube
**LimitNOFILE=65536**
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this, It worked for me

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: What about max file descriptors?

Answer (score 0):

This guide will help if you run SonarQube:
[SonarQube Guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me .

If you want to increase the limit shown by ulimit -n, modify below files.

1. /etc/systemd/user.conf
2. /etc/systemd/system.conf

in both file add the following line in addition

```
  DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
```

3. /etc/security/limits.conf with the following lines

   ```
            *  soft    nofile  65536
            *  hard    nofile  65536
            elasticsearch   soft    nofile  65536
            elasticsearch   hard    nofile  65536
            elasticsearch   memlock unlimited
   ```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me after I do:
vi /etc/security/limits.conf
add following:

- soft nproc 65535
- hard nproc 65535
- soft nofile 65535
- hard nofile 65535

Save and reboot.

Answer (score -2):

Did you read [that page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-descriptors.html)?

It says:

set ulimit -n 65536 as root before starting Elasticsearch, or set nofile to 65536 in /etc/security/limits.conf.

Comment: Even after updating ulimit it results the same.
`max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]`

Comment: You likely need to log out and relogin into the shell of the runner user for the change to take effect. Can verify by executing `ulimit -n`.

Comment: ES is switching versions so fast that above answer for given version and docs may not match. its specially issue in low memory VMs/containers.